# Sum values in a Array of JavaScript deep Objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have been searching for a solution and trying different things to get the solutions i am looking for for hours. I have an array below I want to be able to do two things to the array separately.  (so two separate functions)

Function 1. I want to to sum all the "weight" values.  (i.e  3 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 0)  I have tried using lodash sumBy which does a fine job in summing the simple objects in the array.

Function 2.  I want to be able to iterate through the elements ( I have been trying to flatten the object using lodash  but with no luck.)

I am looking for any help.  I apologize if the is a newbie question or if its something already solved, for some reason I can't find the right search terms.

EDIT: 
Currently using es5, so arrow functions are not available

```js
var answers = [{
    '1': {
      id: '5aa2542e4e31482f1e',
      text: 'Employee',
      orderNo: 2,
      weight: 3,
    },
    '5': {
      id: '5a442e47339482f22',
      text: 'Worker',
      orderNo: 6,
      weight: 2,
    }
  },
  {
    '2': {
      id: '5a52442e4739482f51',
      text: 'Time Sensive',
      orderNo: 3,
      weight: 1,
    },
    '3': {
      id: '5a2442e47e3932f52',
      text: 'Group Sensitive',
      orderNo: 4,
      weight: 2,
    }
  },
  {
    id: '5a57d9375a5a7ac20317',
    text: 'Med',
    orderNo: 1,
    weight: 1
  },
  {
    id: '5a57da0755a7ac4691c',
    text: 'Med ',
    orderNo: 2,
    weight: 1
  },
  {
    id: '5a57da545aa7ac206220',
    text: 'Yes',
    orderNo: 1,
    weight: 0
  }
]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ... Why are there 2 different data formats in that array?

Comment: These where answers from a survey that is sent over to me.  The top portion are from questions that where checkboxs, so users can select more than one element.  The bottom are radio in which there is only one answer.

Comment: `EDIT: Currently using es5, so arrow functions are not available (Yet).` Es5 will never include arrow function because the spec is finished. You can use function () instead

Comment: i didn't mean es5, I meant updating my code to use es6.

Answer (score 0):

The basic solution is to flatten your array

```
const x = answers.map(obj => Object.values(obj))
```

After that you have a array of array

You can join these array using reduce.

```
const flattenedAnswers = x.reduce((acc, item) => acc.concat(item), []);
```

to sum the weight, you can use map and reduce

```
const sum = flattenedAnswers.map(item => item.weigt).reduce((acc, item) => acc + item), 0);
```

To iterate over the items, just iterate over the flattened answers array

```js
var answers = [{
    '1': {
      id: '5aa2542e4e31482f1e',
      text: 'Employee',
      orderNo: 2,
      weight: 3,
    },
    '5': {
      id: '5a442e47339482f22',
      text: 'Worker',
      orderNo: 6,
      weight: 2,
    }
  },
  {
    '2': {
      id: '5a52442e4739482f51',
      text: 'Time Sensive',
      orderNo: 3,
      weight: 1,
    },
    '3': {
      id: '5a2442e47e3932f52',
      text: 'Group Sensitive',
      orderNo: 4,
      weight: 2
    }
  }
]

const flat = answers.map(x => Object.values(x)).reduce((acc, item) => acc.concat(item), []);

const sum = flat.map(x => x.weight).reduce((acc, item) => acc + item, 0);

console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate the array elements by `answers.forEach(answer => {...})`

You can iterate the answer properties by `Object.keys(answer).forEach(key => {let val = answer[key]})`

Look for the Weight property in each `answer` *and* in each *val*, and if it's there, add it to a variable you've defined outside of the foreach functions.